# .net application.settings different behaviour on Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-xp

I'm using `application.settings` (not `app.config`) to store username and password for a user.

When installing the app on Windows 7 everything goes great, but once installing the app on Windows XP it seems that `application.settings` is unreachable and the app gets empty strings.

How can I solve this?

Comment: which version of xp is it, as it is only supported on Windows 7, Windows Vista SP1 or later, Windows XP SP3, Windows XP SP2 x64 Edition, Windows Server 2008 (Server Core not supported), Windows Server 2008 R2 (Server Core supported with SP1 or later), Windows Server 2003 SP2

Comment: so what can i do for xp SP1 or XP without SP ?

Comment: This sounds just like normal, installing your program isn't going to reproduce any setting values with User scope you had on your dev machine.  You always need to deal with having no setting value when the program is run for the first time.

Comment: So if i will set the settings propertiex for the first time the settings file will be created ? why is it that on windows 7 it does deploy the initial settings ?